# Java Help Interest Rate

Tags: java, rate

Hey guys i'm coding this program and i have everything working except for the interest rate which brings out this error,

```
MenuDrivenProgram.java:92: possible loss of precision
found : double
required: int
deposit = balanceCurrent + interest;
^
1 error
```

Here is my code,

```
public static void InvestmentReport()
    {
        System.out.printf("*** Investment Report stub ***\n");
        // This is where your Part A solution goes
        System.out.printf("*************** InvestmentReport Menu ***************\n\n");
        Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
        int deposit, monthly, interestRate;
        double interest, balanceCurrent;
        System.out.println ("Enter your initial deposit amount in dollars\n");
        deposit = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("Enter the annual interest rate as a percentage (eg. 6.0)\n");
        interest = console.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("Enter your monthly deposit amount in dollars\n");
        monthly = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("Savings growth over the next 6 months:\n");

        System.out.println ("Balance after first month: $" + deposit);
        deposit = deposit + monthly;
        System.out.println ("Interest earned for this month: $" + interest);
        interest = balanceCurrent * interestRate / 12 / 100;
        deposit = balanceCurrent + interest;

        System.out.println ("Balance after second month: $" + deposit);
        deposit = deposit + monthly;
        System.out.println ("Interest earned for this month:\n");

        System.out.println ("Balance after third month: $" + deposit);
        deposit = deposit + monthly;
        System.out.println ("Interest earned for this month:\n");

        System.out.println ("Balance after fourth month: $" + deposit);
        deposit = deposit + monthly;
        System.out.println ("Interest earned for this month:\n");

        System.out.println ("Balance after fifth month: $" + deposit);
        deposit = deposit + monthly;
        System.out.println ("Interest earned for this month:\n");

        System.out.println ("Balance after sixth month: $" + deposit);
        deposit = deposit + monthly;
        System.out.println ("Interest earned for this month:\n");
    }
```

Anyone able to tell me what i've done wrong and how to fix it? Cheers

Comment: It gives you a hint: `possible loss of precision found : double required`

Comment: Your deposit is an int, so you are losing the decimal values within interest.  If this is what you intended you can manually cast the double to an int.

Comment: Or, better yet, make all those int variables double.  Can't you have 4.2% interest?

Comment: I tried but still not working anyone able to give me the code? Cheers

Comment: Ctrl+F --> Replace --> int with double

Answer (score 1):

Declare deposit as double.

```
double deposit = 0D;
```

Or, you can cast the value to int.

```
deposit = (int) balanceCurrent + interest;
```

But deposit is an amount and you should not lose the cent value (decimal part) I suppose.

Comment: Thanks i changed all the variables to double but now i get these 2 error messages,

Comment: MenuDrivenProgram.java:90: variable balanceCurrent might not have been initialized
        interest = balanceCurrent * interestRate / 12 / 100;
                   ^
MenuDrivenProgram.java:90: variable interestRate might not have been initialized
        interest = balanceCurrent * interestRate / 12 / 100;
                                    ^
2 errors

Comment: @user2681686 As I showed you in the code snippet above, you need to initialize your local variables. double deposit = 0D, monthly = 0D, interestRate = 0D, interest = 0D, balanceCurrent = 0D;